# How to express hasattr() duck typing logic with structural pattern matching?

Tags: python, duck-typing, python-3.10, structural-pattern-matching

I have code that checks for [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-named-tuple) and [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-dataclasses) by looking for a `_fields` attribute:

```
if hasattr(candidate, '_fields'):
    do_action()
```

How can I express this with Python 3.10's match/case structural pattern matching?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Understanding the documentation

[PEP 634](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/) for structural pattern matching documents this capability as a [class pattern](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/#class-patterns):

- Writing `cls()` will do an [isinstance()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) test.
- Adding a keyword pattern `cls(attr=variable)` tests for the presence of an attribute and binds the value to the variable.

To emulate a [hasattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) for [duck typing](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-duck-typing):

- Set *cls* to *object* so that any class can match.
- Set *attr* to `_fields`, the attribute that must be present.
- Set *variable* to `_` if you don't need to capture the value or to some other variable name if you do want to capture the value.

### This specific example

Your specific example, `if hasattr(candidate, '_fields'): do_action()`, translates to:

```
match candidate:
   case object(_fields=_):
       do_action()
```

### Complete worked-out example

This shows how all the parts fit together:

```
from typing import NamedTuple
from dataclasses import dataclass

class Whale(NamedTuple):
    name: str
    num_fins: int

@dataclass
class Vehicle:
    name: str
    num_wheels: int

subject = Vehicle('bicycle', 2)
    
match subject:
    case object(num_fins=n):
        print(f'Found {n} fins')
    case object(num_wheels=_):
        print(f'Found wheeled object')
    case _:
        print('Unknown')
```

This script outputs:

```
Found wheeled object
```